# How can I install ROS Melodic with Python3?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to use ROS with a library that does not support Python 2, which is over a decade old at this point.
I'm finding mixed information about Python 3 support in ROS Melodic.

I'm installing from source using the instructions on the wiki.
I used Python 3 to install the initial packages

```
sudo pip3 install -U rosdep rosinstall_generator wstool rosinstall
```

After setting up my locale correctly, I got up to the point where `wstool` has initialised the standalone workspace.
But after that I run `rosdep` to install all the dependencies, and I see a lot of Python 2 packages scrolling by.

```
rosdep install --os=debian:stretch --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro melodic --skip-keys=sbcl -y
```

Is there a way ROS Melodic can run on Python 3?

It might be worth mentioning that I could not care less about what the whole system runs on, as long as I can have a single Python 3 node to receive some messages and use this particular Python library. So if I can install `rospy` on Python 3 that should be enough I think?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295012/how-can-i-install-ros-melodic-with-python3?/) by [pepijndevos](https://answers.ros.org/users/35881/pepijndevos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2018-06-22

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosdep install step would install python 2 versions of the package since that's how the dependencies are defined. Instead of hunting down the list of dependencies and installing python 3 version of each, it might be easier to just start building and install the missing python 3 package if there is an error. You will need to set the env variable `ROS_PYTHON_VERSION` to 3 when building to force python 3 otherwise by default it picks python 2.

Also if you just want basic functionality, you probably want to use the `ROS-Comm` build as described on the [Installation page](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Source).

---

Originally posted by [kartikmohta](https://answers.ros.org/users/524/kartikmohta/) with karma: 308 on 2018-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pepijndevos](https://answers.ros.org/users/35881/pepijndevos/) on 2018-06-23**:
The installation worked after installing empy, but it seems messages are not properly generated. On python 3 there is no module named geometry_msgs, and in Python 2 the module geometry_msgs has no msg submodule.

**Comment by [kartikmohta](https://answers.ros.org/users/524/kartikmohta/) on 2018-06-23**:
The `ROS-Comm` meta-package does not contain the `geometry_msgs` package. You can add the extra packages you want to the `rosinstall_generator` line when generating your workspace, for example use `rosinstall_generator ros_comm geometry_msgs --rosdistro melodic --deps --tar` for adding geometry_msgs